# Python: How to bin a set of data by a repeated value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say, I have a numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np

x= np.array(
    [[100, 14, 12, 15],
    [100, 21, 16, 11],
    [100, 19, 10, 13],
    [160, 24, 15, 12],
    [160, 43, 12, 65],
    [160, 17, 53, 23],
    [300, 15, 17, 11],
    [300, 66, 23, 12],
    [300, 44, 70, 19]])
```

The original array is much bigger, so my question is if there's a way to bin or group rows based on the value on column 1?
for example:

```
{'100': [[14, 12, 15], [21, 16, 11], [19, 10, 13]],
,'160': [[24, 15, 12], [43, 12, 65], [17, 53, 23]],
,'300': [[15, 17, 11], [66, 23, 12], [44, 70, 19]]}
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the result?  That will likely determine which method for creating and storing the groups is most effective.

Comment: Is the first column necessarily sorted?

Answer (score 2):

We are talking about large dataset, so we might need the performance, as also we have the input data as a NumPy array. Listed in this post are two NumPy approaches.

**Approach #1**

Here's one approach using `np.unique` to get the row indices separating groups and then using a loop comprehension to get the dictionary output -

```
unq, idx = np.unique(x[:,0], return_index=1)
idx1 = np.r_[idx,x.shape[0]]
dict_out = {unq[i]:x[idx1[i]:idx1[i+1],1:] for i in range(len(unq))}
```

This assumes the first column to be sorted as stated in the question title - `...repeated value in one column`. If that's not the case, we need to use `x[:,0].argsort()` to sort the rows of `x` and then proceed.

Sample input, output -

```
In [41]: x
Out[41]: 
array([[100,  14,  12,  15],
       [100,  21,  16,  11],
       [100,  19,  10,  13],
       [160,  24,  15,  12],
       [160,  43,  12,  65],
       [160,  17,  53,  23],
       [300,  15,  17,  11],
       [300,  66,  23,  12],
       [300,  44,  70,  19]])

In [42]: dict_out
Out[42]: 
{100: array([[14, 12, 15],
        [21, 16, 11],
        [19, 10, 13]]), 160: array([[24, 15, 12],
        [43, 12, 65],
        [17, 53, 23]]), 300: array([[15, 17, 11],
        [66, 23, 12],
        [44, 70, 19]])}
```

**Approach #2**

Here's another getting rid of `np.unique` for further performance boost -

```
idx1 = np.concatenate(([0],np.flatnonzero(x[1:,0] != x[:-1,0])+1, [x.shape[0]]))
dict_out = {x[i,0]:x[i:j,1:] for i,j in zip(idx1[:-1], idx1[1:])}
```

---

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
# @COLDSPEED's soln
from collections import defaultdict
def defaultdict_app(x):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for l in x:
        data[l[0]].append(l[1:])

# @David Z's soln-1
import pandas as pd
def pandas_groupby_app(x):
    df = pd.DataFrame(x)
    return {key: group.iloc[:,1:] for key, group in df.groupby(0)}

# @David Z's soln-2
import itertools as it
def groupby_app(x):
    return {key: list(map(list, group)) for key, group in \
                        it.groupby(x, lambda row: row[0])}

# Proposed in this post    
def numpy_app1(x):
    unq, idx = np.unique(x[:,0], return_index=1)
    idx1 = np.r_[idx,x.shape[0]]
    return {unq[i]:x[idx1[i]:idx1[i+1],1:] for i in range(len(unq))}

# Proposed in this post    
def numpy_app2(x):
    idx1 = np.concatenate(([0],np.flatnonzero(x[1:,0] != x[:-1,0])+1, [x.shape[0]]))
    return {x[i,0]:x[i:j,1:] for i,j in zip(idx1[:-1], idx1[1:])}
```

Timings -

```
In [84]: x = np.random.randint(0,100,(10000,4))

In [85]: x[:,0].sort()

In [86]: %timeit defaultdict_app(x)
    ...: %timeit pandas_groupby_app(x)
    ...: %timeit groupby_app(x)
    ...: %timeit numpy_app1(x)
    ...: %timeit numpy_app2(x)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.43 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 310 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 75.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: If it's pre-sorted, it's possible `unq = np.array(set(x[:, 0]))` and `idx1=np.r_[np.searchsorted(x, unq), x.shape[0]]` in `numpy_app1` might be faster.  Or just doing `searchsorted` instead of returning `idx` from `np.unique` (which I think is the slow bit).

Comment: @DanielF Yeah, Approach #2 explicitly leverages that sorted nature and proved to be much more efficient than with `np.unique`. I rolled out `np.unique` version with the intention of a compact code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this as [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you might want to do it using `DataFrame`'s [`groupby()` functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). You'd create a `DataFrame` from your original array

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

and group by the first column; then you can iterate over the resulting `GroupBy` object to get the groups of the frame which have all the same result in the first column.

```
{key: group for key, group in df.groupby(0)}
```

Of course, in this snippet `group` includes the first column. You can strip it out using indexing:

```
{key: group.iloc[:,1:] for key, group in df.groupby(0)}
```

and if you would like to convert the sub-frames back into Numpy arrays, use `group.iloc[:,1:].values` instead. (If you want them as lists of lists, as indicated in your question, it shouldn't be hard to write a function to make that conversion, but it'll probably be more efficient to keep it in Pandas or at least Numpy if you can.)

An alternative is to use the OG [`groupby()` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which lets you avoid Pandas (if you have some reason for doing so) and use a plain old iterative approach.

```
import itertools as it
{key: list(map(list, group))
    for key, group in it.groupby(x, lambda row: row[0])}
```

This, again, includes the key in the resulting rows, but you can trim it out using indexing

```
{key: list(map(lambda a: list(a)[1:], group))
    for key, group in it.groupby(x, lambda row: row[0])}
```

You can make the code a tad cleaner by using the [`groupby_transform()` function from the more-itertools module](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.groupby_transform) (which is not included in the standard Python library):

```
import more_itertools as mt
{key: list(group) for key, group in mt.groupby_transform(
    x, lambda row: row[0], lambda row: list(row[1:])
)}
```

---

<sup>Disclosure: I contributed the `groupby_transform()` function to more-itertools</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can group your data with the `collections.defaultdict` and a loop.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
for l in x:
    data[l[0]].append(l[1:])

print(dict(data))
```

Output:

```
{100: [[14, 12, 15], [21, 16, 11], [19, 10, 13]],
 160: [[24, 15, 12], [43, 12, 65], [17, 53, 23]],
 300: [[15, 17, 11], [66, 23, 12], [44, 70, 19]]}
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: @Jelmed12 What he said. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this

**After Edit**

```
ls_dict={}
for ls in x:
    key=ls[0]
    value=[ls[1:]]
    if key in ls_dict:
        value = ls[1:]
        ls_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        value = [ls[1:]]
        ls_dict[key]=value
print(ls_dict)
```

**output**

```
{100: [[14, 12, 15], [21, 16, 11], [19, 10, 13]], 160: [[24, 15, 12], [43, 12, 65], [17, 53, 23]], 300: [[15, 17, 11], [66, 23, 12], [44, 70, 19]]}
```